# Include CSS file in Drupal 8 custom module with multiple routings

Tags: php, css, symfony, drupal, drupal-8

I would like to include a CSS file into my custom module in Drupal 8. I already have another module with only one routing path and one controller function and my CSS works fine there, but not so in the new module. Do I miss something, or is there anything different with multiple routing paths?

`module.routing.yml`:

```
module.support_bugs:
  path: '/support/bugs'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\module\Controller\moduleController::bugsShow'
    _title: ''
  requirements:
    _permission: 'support_bugs'

module.support_requests:
  path: '/support/requests/{param1}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\module\Controller\moduleController::requestsShow'
    _title: ''
    param1: null
  requirements:
    _permission: 'support_requests'

module.support_docs:
  path: '/support/docs'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\module\Controller\moduleController::docsShow'
    _title: ''
  requirements:
    _permission: 'support_docs'
```

I want to include the CSS for the output of `support_changes`.

`module.library.yml`:

```
module.support_requests:
  css:
    theme:
       src/css/modulestyle.css: {}
```

And in the end, I include it in my controller.

`moduleController.php`:

```
namespace Drupal\module\Controller;

class moduleController {

    //other functions

    public static function requestsShow($filter=null){

    //some code inhere

    $build['content'] = array(
      '#markup' => $output);
    $build['#attached']['library'][] = 'module/module.support_requests';
    return $build;
    }

    //other functions

}
```

Answer (score 2):

May be because of the conflict in same key "module.support_requests" in routing.yml and library.yml files.
Try changing the key in *module.library.yml* into "**support_requests**" and add the library as *$build['#attached']['library'][] = 'module/**support_requests**';*

Comment: thanks for the effort but found the solution some time ago. it was a typo: it has to be libraries.yml. drupal needs this static.